Definition trouble: Faces of convex sets
I'm reading up on faces of convex sets, and after some playing around with them, it looks to me that any union of faces is a face, while my book says that this is not so:
Let $S\subseteqℝ^n$ be a convex set, and $F\subseteq S$.
By definition,  $F$ is a face of $S$, iff
$$
\forall x,y\in S:\forall\alpha\in\left(0,1\right):\;\;\alpha x+\left(1-\alpha\right)y\in F\;\Rightarrow\; x,y\in F\tag{1}
$$
Define a bilaterally admissible direction $d$ in a point $x\in S$ to be a vector $d\inℝ^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $x+\epsilon_1 d,x-\epsilon_2 d\in S$ for some $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$.
If I'm not mistaken, we can characterize a face $F\subseteq S$ as follows:
$F$ is a face iff for any point $m\in F$ and any in $m$ admissible direction $d$, we have $m+\epsilon d\in S\Rightarrow m+\epsilon d\in F$. That is, moving from $m$ along an admissible direction, we fall out of $F$ exactly when we fall out of $S$.
We can therefore define a hull operator ${\mathrm{ExtF}}_S$, which takes in a subset $M\subseteq S$ and outputs the smallest face containing $M$ by just adding all points in $S$ reachable by going along bilaterally admissible directions:
$$
{\mathrm{ExtF}}_S:P\left(S\right)\rightarrow P\left(S\right),
\quad 
M\mapsto 
\bigcup_{
m\in M\\ 
d \text{ is a bilaterally admissible direction in } m\\
\epsilon\inℝ\\
p:=m+\epsilon d\in S}
\{p\}
$$
As a hull operator, the fixed points of ${\mathrm{ExtF}}_S$ should be precisely the faces.
And since the operator only looks at one point $m\in M$ at a time, we especially have that ${\mathrm{ExtF}}_S(M)= {\mathrm{ExtF}}_S(M_1)\cup {\mathrm{ExtF}}_S(M_2) $ for any partition $M=M_1\cup M_2$.
Now let $S$ be a cube in $ℝ^3$. Each of its squares is a face. Take two disjunct squares (i.e. the parallel squares). Then, since each is a face, their union should be a face as well.
But my book now says that for any convex set $S$ and face $F\subseteq S$, we have
$$
F= S \cap \text{aff}(F)
$$
, and for the parallel squares, this affine hull should be the whole of $ℝ^3$, so the union can't be a face.
Where did I get things wrong?

What you're missing is that a face of $S$ is required to be a convex subset of $S$.

So, the characterization with admissible directions works out as long as we add a convexity requirement, right? To me the convexity restriction looks like it hardly interacts with (1)

I.e. $F$ is a face iff $F$ is convex, and for any point $m\in F$ and any in $m$ admissible direction $d$, we have $m+\epsilon d\in S\Rightarrow m+\epsilon d\in F$
